# Why does Specs2 run these `sequential` tests in random order?

Tags: scala, integration-testing, specs2, playframework-2.1

There's an old database test suite that I'm trying to migrate from Specs to [Specs2](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/). However, Specs2 runs the tests in a weird order (from my point of view), which breaks the tests since they change the database state, and run certain code twice.

Find below a simplified version of the tests. As far as I've understood, the tests should run in this order: (since I've specified *sequential*):
`! 222`, `! 333`, `! 444`
However, what actually happens, is that they're executed in this order:
`! 333`, `! 222`, `! 444`

Here are the tests:

```
object IncludedSpec extends Specification {
  sequential
  println("sssstart")

  "IncludedSpec" should {

    println("..222")
    "context free block" >> {
      println("....! 222 the first test")
      1 === 1
    }

    var variableN = 0

    "block with context" >> {
      println("....333")
      "using one variable" >> {
        println("......! 333 doing some tests and setting variableN")
        variableN = 123
      }

      println("....444")
      "using it again" >> {
        println("......! 444 testing variableN")
        variableN === 123
      }
      println("....555")
    }
  }

  println("eeeend")
}
```

Here is all `println` output:

```
sssstart
eeeend
sssstart
eeeend
..222
....333
......! 333 doing some tests and setting variableN
....444
....555
....! 222 the first test
......! 444 testing variableN
```

And my two questions:

1. Why isn't `! 222` executed first?
2. How is it possible that `sssstart eeeend` is output twice? The spec is an object and isn't created twice?

Oddly enough, if I remove the side effects from the tests — that is, removing *variableN* and replacing the test bodies with `ok` — the tests run in the correct order.

Version details: I'm running these tests with Paly Framework 2.1-SNAPSHOT (version 203df0e from October 28 2012) and Scala 2.10.0-RC1. I think the Specs2 version bundled with Play is version 1.12, because the `inline` method is available, and it was added in 1.12(-SNAPSHOT), see https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/issues/87 and there are no later Specs2 versions.

(Oh, and if you think I should completely rewrite the tests, then have a look at this question instead: [How design a Specs2 database test, with interdependent tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174893/how-design-a-specs2-database-test-with-interdependent-tests) )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Originally, in specs2, you could create the following:

1 - an example with `in`: `"this is an example" in { 1 must_== 1 }`

2 - an example with `>>`: `"this is an example" >> { 1 must_== 1 }`

3 - a block of examples with `>>`

```
"this system should" >> {
  "do something" >> ok
  "do something else" >> ok
}
```

The important thing was that `in` was reserved for examples alone and accepted anything that could be converted to a `Result`. On the other hand `>>` could be used for both examples and groups of examples (to have a uniform style of nesting) so it accepted values of type `Example` or `Result`.

Now things started to become a bit more complicated when you wanted to do the following:

1 - use `foreach` to create a group of examples

```
"this group has 5 examples" in {
  (1 to 5) foreach { i => "example "+i >> ok }
}
```

2 - use `foreach` to create a group of expectations

```
"this example has 5 expectations" in {
  (1 to 5) foreach { i => i must_== i }
}
```

The trouble is, those 2 expressions with `foreach` both have type `Unit`. But they're doing 2 very different things! The first one is building examples, so this expression needs to be evaluated right away to build the `Specification`. The second one is creating the body of an `Example` and will be executed later (or maybe never if the example is filtered out for example). Two things, with the same operator `>>`, that cannot work.

So it was decided that `>>(block: =>Unit)` means "this builds a group of examples by a side-effect", and `in(expectations: =>Unit)` means "this builds the body of an `Example` probably having expectations which will be a side-effect.

Now, when this explains a bit better why you're seeing a strange order with your print statements:

```
..222
....333
......! 333 doing some tests and setting variableN
....444
....555
```

are printed first because they are contained in blocks of type `Unit`, interpreted as groups of Examples.

And :

```
....! 222 the first test
......! 444 testing variableN
```

are printed consequently because they are in blocks of type `MatchResult[_]`, that is, they are considered as the body of examples.

I agree that this is confusing and I hope that this explanation brings some perspective on why things are the way they are. Of course another lesson is "side-effects are sneaky because they don't tell you what they are really doing".

So the general specs2 tip is to always end your blocks with proper values (unless you use a `foreach` construct as shown in my example above). For example, adding `ok` at the end of the blocks where you do a variable assignment should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation! Yes now I notice that `in` and `>>` [here in FragmentBuilder](https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/blob/1.12.2/src/main/scala/org/specs2/mutable/FragmentsBuilder.scala#L51) accept both blocks and example fragments, and take different actions depending on what they got.

Comment: Perhaps it'd be reasonable to mention this new (for Specs2?) behavior in the [Specs to Specs2 migration guide](http://etorreborre.blogspot.se/2011/05/specs2-migration-guide.html)?  I didn't notice this issue with `>>` and `in` until now, because Specs 1 worked with all versions of Scala up to 2.9.x, and there was no need for me to migrate to Specs2. — But now there is no version of Specs 1 for Scala 2.10, so I needed to migrate to Specs2. Perhaps more people will migrate to Specs2 soon. (Well unless of course you build Specs 1 for Scala 2.10)

Comment: Perhaps `foreach` to create a group of examples shouldn't have been allowed? Instead, one could have required that people use `(1 to 5) map (...)`, to yield a list of examples — with type List[Example] (or something like that). Then it'd been possible to differentiate between construction of nested examples, and construction of expectations?

Comment: Now I've added `ok` at the end of some test fragments, and the test suite works okay again :-)

Comment: This tool is useless for me if I can't control execution order..I'm going back to JUnit - at lest it just works.

Comment: In specs2 3.x it is not possible anymore to pass `Unit` blocks when building  specifications to avoid the problem in this question. Did you have other execution order issues?

Answer (score 0):

*(Update: This didn't work with my real rather huge Spec. It's still being executed in seemingly random order, Specs2 seems to start somewhere in the middle. — However when I did the below-mentioned replacement on a smaller Spec with perhaps 10 or 20 examples, it really did result in the spec being executed in the correct order. Weird*)

Here's a partial workaround, but not really an answer:

Use `in` instead of `>>`, before the test fragments. Then the tests are executed in the correct order.  (But `sssstart eeeend` still happens twice.)

So this works as intended: (I've replaced certain `>>` with `in`)

```
object IncludedSpec extends Specification {
  sequential
  println("sssstart")

  "IncludedSpec" should {

    println("..222")
    "context free block" in {   // not >>
      println("....! 222 the first test")
      1 === 1
    }

    var variableN = 0

    "block with context" >> {
      println("....333")
      "using one variable" in {   // not >>
        println("......! 333 doing some tests and setting variableN")
        variableN = 123
      }

      println("....444")
      "using it again" in {   // not >>
        println("......! 444 testing variableN")
        variableN === 123
      }
      println("....555")
    }
  }

  println("eeeend")
}
```

---

My confused thoughts below:

1.

I think that a difference between `in` and `>>` is that:
`in` can only appear before test fragments (that is, a `{... x must_== y ... }` block). But
`>>` can appear both before whole examples (with nested test fragments) and before test fragments.

So when I'm writing `>>`, Specs2 doesn't know directly what to expect. I don't know why this would change the test execution order though. Unless Specs2 needs to ... execute some code inside the `{ ...}` block to find out? But doesn't Specs2 use reflection? This feels weird.

2.

If the tests have no side effects at all (in this case, update no shared `var`s). Or if *all* tests have side effects. Then they are, as far as I can tell, executed in the correct order. *However*, if some tests have no side effects, except for *reading* a shared `var`, then they seem to be executed *after* tests that write to a `var`. (If you use `>>` instead of `in`.) This also feels weird. Anyway I suppose that soon I'll start porting my tests to Specs2 and replacing `>>` with `in` :-)